# Creating child theme out of Coeur

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, parent-theme

I have been spending days looking into edit my theme. I understand that in order to edit the footer of my parent theme i would need to create a child theme.

So here is my child theme folder on the same level as my other themes.

[image: mythemefolder]

As you can see I have my **coeur-child** folder created.

Here is the files under that folder

[image: child theme files]

Here is what contains in my `style.css` of the child theme

```
 themes/coeur-child/style.css
 /*
 Theme Name:   Coeur
 Theme URI:    http://frenchtastic.eu/theme/coeur
 Description:  Coeur Child Theme
 Author:       frenchtastic
 Author URI:   http://frenchtastic.eu/about
 Template:     Coeur
 Version:      3.1.4
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 Tags:         blog, e-commerce, one-column, two-columns, left-sidebar,       right-sidebar, custom-colors, editor-style, microformats, custom-  background, custom-menu, featured-images, post-formats, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready 
Text Domain:  Coeur-child
*/
```

In my `themes/coeur-child/functions.php`

```
     <?php
     function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'coeur-style'; // Coeur This is 'coeur-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

      wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
       );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
  ?>
```

I copied the footer from my parent theme into my child theme folder

```
 <!-- <button class="mobileCart">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
   </button> -->

   <footer>
        <?php if(is_active_sidebar('footer-1') or is_active_sidebar('footer-2') or is_active_sidebar('footer-3')): ?>
       <div class="footer-top">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-1' ); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 md-footer-cl">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-2' ); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-3' ); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
     <div class="blog-footer blog-footer-widgets">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="site-credits">&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> </p>
            <p class="back-to-top"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">      </i> <?php echo __('Back to top', 'coeur'); ?><a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
       <?php else: ?>
      <div class="blog-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="site-credits">&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> - </p>
            <p class="back-to-top"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"> </i> <?php echo __('Back to top', 'coeur'); ?><a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
  </footer>

   </div> <!-- end of wrap -->

   <?php wp_footer(); ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

got the following error

```
  Broken Themes

  The following themes are installed but incomplete.

  Name  Description     
  Coeur The parent theme is missing. Please install the "Coeur" parent       theme. Delete  Install Parent Theme
```

I am using WordPress version 4.8 & WooCommerce version 3.1.0

I searched for `wp_enqueue_style` in my parent **coeur** folder but child is not getting my **coeur-style**.

can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: **coeur** or **Coeur**? recheck template name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure template name is correct.

> Template – the name of the parent theme directory. The parent theme in
>   your example is the Coeur theme, so the Template will be
>   coeur

also make change theme name.
for more information [Click Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: Thank you. So likewise, the 'Author:       John Doe' and
 'Author URI:   http://example.com' Should be changed accordingly.  Thank you.